# SliverAppBar not scrolling when nested ListView uses a ScrollController

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
final _controller = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build() {
  return NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) => [SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 300)],
    body: ListView.builder(
      controller: _controller, // Removing this solves the issue. 
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text('$i'),
    ),
  );
}
```

If I scroll my `ListView`, the `SliverAppBar` doesn't scroll but if I remove the `controller` property then it does scroll.

So, how can I use the controller and make the `SliverAppBar` to scroll with the `ListView` (i.e. the standard behavior)?

---

**Note**: I don't want to use the `CustomScrollView` as my tree hierarchy won't let me make use of it that well.

Comment: I have read the docs that I shouldn't provide a `ScrollController` to the nested `ListView` but the question is **how can I make it work (even if docs say you shouldn't)**

Comment: What do you need to use the controller for?

Comment: @MichaelHorn I could have set the `ScrollController` to `NestedScrollView` but  I want to scroll to the last position in the `ListView`, which `NestedScrollView` can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the child is wrapped

```
final _controller = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build() {
  return NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) => [SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 300)],
    body: ListView.builder(
      //add this to the child ListView
      shrinkWrap: true
      controller: _controller, // Removing this solves the issue. 
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text('$i'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This makes it load all children immediately and thus defeats the purpose of using a ListView.

Comment: @user1032613 Correct but even setting the `shrinkWrap: true` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @iDecode Correct but neither of us downvoted this post lol.

Answer (score -1):

Just move the scroll controller to NestedScrollView like this:

```
Widget build() {
  return NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) => [SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 300)],
    body: ListView.builder(
      //add this to the child ListView
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text('$i'),
    ),
    controller: _controller,
  );
}
```

That worked for me, I had a waterfalls flow using the scroll controller. and I need the sliver appear style.

Comment: Thanks but I need the controller for my `ListView`, your answer defeats that purpose. What if I now do `controller.jumpTo(200)`, it will also scroll the `SliverAppBar` and this is what I don't want.

Comment: Hi @iDecode, by any chance you able to solve this issue?
I am in quite same situation.

Comment: @BishawjitDas You had the same issue but still you didn't upvote my post. So, how do you expect me to share the answer with you, :) But don't upvote it now because I won't tell you how I did it. For future, develop a habit of upvoting posts in a good spirit.